# Ajax success and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel-5

I'm currently working on a project using Laravel platform.
I'm trying to delete data from a model asynchronously using ajax. And when all is done my data should be removed from the table. My code runs perfectly, data are being removed from my database , yet "tr" elements arent really faded or removed. Here is my code :
[ajax sucess not really working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWHKG.png)

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-remove-interview' , function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('data-interview-id');
    $.ajax({
        url: './manage/interviews/destroy/'+id ,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: id,
        success: function (data) {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Please paste your code here. Links die.

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove-interview' , function() {


  var id = $(this).attr('data-interview-id');
  $.ajax({
     url: './manage/interviews/destroy/'+id ,
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: id,


     success: function (data){

  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
 }
 });
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was by removing dataType json . My function doesnt return any data .

Answer (score 1):

**Use**

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

**Instead of**

```
$(this).parents("tr").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `success` function callback within your ajax request no long refers to the button when you use `this`. You need to get an explicit variable to the button if you want to use it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-remove-interview' , function() {

    // Get this button as a variable so we can use it later
    var el = $(this);

    var id = $(this).attr('data-interview-id');

    $.ajax({
        url: './manage/interviews/destroy/'+id ,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: id,
        success: function (data) {
            $(el).parents("tr").remove();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: i didn't get it well , so i add a new id or class for my tr ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: Yes. And then inside the `success` callback you need to use `el` instead of `this` because `this` now refers to the closure it is inside of and not the outer element.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML structure, its hard to tell if the code is correct. Is the  element with class `btn-remove-interview` INSIDE of the `tr`? Do like @jonju said and use `closest()` instead. https://www.sitepoint.com/jquerys-closest-parents/

Comment: it tried @jonju way but it didnt work , you want to check my HTML code ?